# How to implicitly pass class manifest for a return value

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Say I define the generic function below:

```
def convert[R](json: String)(implicit m: Manifest[R]): R =
  parse(json).extract[R]
```

I am not sure what the correct syntax for calling this function would be? I have tried:

```
 convert(json).asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```

Seems to compile correctly but get an exception when I try to extract the json. I can get it to work correctly by defining the following for example:

```
def convert[R](json: String)(cb: R => Unit)(implicit m: Manifest[R]) =
  cb(parse(json).extract[R])
```

And then doing the following:

```
 convert(json) { ret: MyClass => // }
```

But is not the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `convert[MyClass](json)`; that's the syntax for explicitly specifying a type parameter. Allowing the type to be inferred by putting it in a context where it's given, something like `convert(json): MyClass`, might also work.